# How to use if in input?

Tags: reactjs

How can I set 'checked', when I have props.a? I can`t understand how to write something, like this:

```
<input if (props.a > x) {checked='checked'}/>
```

I tried `<input {props.a > x ? 'checked' : ''}/>`, but I had an error

Comment: Did you try like this? `<input checked={props.a > x ? 'checked' : null />` or may be `<input checked={props.a > x ? true : false />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can asssigned checked to a state value and control this state in `componentWillReceiveProps` function as it will be called whenever props change
like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.a > x) {
         this.setState({checked: 'checked'});
    }

}

<input checked={this.state.checked}/>
```

or else you can return a value directly in put with props like

```
<input checked={(props.a > x)? 'checked': null}}/>
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var a = 10;
    var x = 9;
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={(a > x)? 'checked': null}/></div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<input checked={ (props.a > x) } />`.